# if $\sin{(ax)}+\sin{(bx)}=\sin{(cx)}+\sin{(dx)}$,show $a=c$ or $a=d$

Tags: trigonometry

> let $a,b,c,d>0$ and such for any real numbers $x\in R$ have
>   $$\sin{(ax)}+\sin{(bx)}=\sin{(cx)}+\sin{(dx)}$$
>   show that
>   $a=c$ or $a=d$

I try it,becasue 
$$\sin{\left(\dfrac{(a+b)x}{2}\right)}\cos{\left(\dfrac{(a-b)x}{2}\right)}=\sin{\left(\dfrac{(c+d)x}{2}\right)}\cos{\left(\dfrac{(c-d)x}{2}\right)}$$
then I don't known how to continue

Comment: Are you sure that the question is right??

Comment: $\sin (x)+\sin(-x)=0=\sin(2x)+\sin(-2x)$.

Comment: We have $a,b,c,d>0$ !

Comment: @Fred  Ah, true.  That's not in the header but it does appear in the body of the question.

Comment: @Fred see my answer!

Comment: I have seen your answer. But the statement is: if $\sin{(ax)}+\sin{(bx)}=\sin{(cx)}+\sin{(dx)}$ for all(!) $x$, then $a=c$ or $a=d$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you differentiate  and put $x=0$, you get $a+b=c+d$. Derivating two more time and putting again $x=0$, you get $a^3+b^3=c^3+d^3$. Simplifying by $a+b=c+d>0$ gives $a^2-ab+b^2=c^2-cd+d^2$, hence $(a+b)^2-3ab=(c+d)^2-3cd$ and $ab=cd$.  It is easy to finish.

Comment: Alternatively, you can repeatedly differentiate and get $a^n + b^n = c^n + d^n$ for a sequence of $n\to \infty$, which implies $\max(a, b) = \max(c, d)$.